# Circular vs Miter Saw Blade difference?

Tags: metal-cutting, circular-saw

Why do manufactures distinguish whether a blade is for a circular saw or miter saw? Is there difference that I'm not seeing?

One of the reasons I'm asking this is that I'm determining the safest way to cut aluminum while not ruining the tool or consumable. It seems the only blade designed for metal cutting available at my local big box store is a segmented diamond blade LENOX METALMAX [1972924](https://www.lenoxtools.com/pages/lenox-metalmax.aspx#ltImg[mixed]/5/). The diameter, arbor hole, kerf or max speed parameters should work for my [DeWalt 7-1/4" miter saw.](https://www.dewalt.com/products/power-tools/saws/miter-saws/20v-max-7-14-sliding-miter-saw-wbattery--charger/dcs361m1) The biggest risk seems to be the lack of protection on the lower guard given a 1/4" blade diameter difference, which seems like a marginal risk since it seems designed for circular saw.

I know carbide blades, likely the more teeth the better should work as [detailed in this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41762/how-can-i-cut-aluminum-angle-stock-without-damaging-my-tools), nevertheless I'm looking for the best option, not one that will work.

Comment: I'd use a carbide blade unless you have hundreds of cuts to make. Those diamond wheels will probably be slow, and as noted on that page, there's a risk of chip-welding if you don't lubricate properly.

Comment: Possibly tooth count? I use carbide blades in my skill saw all the time to cut sheet metal roofing and aluminum sheeting. We have a metal cutting “skill style” saw at work it catches the metal chips and has a high tooth count but those blades are way expensive it really doesn’t do much better than my old worm drive skill saw.

Comment: What are you cutting? How many cuts? How precise do you need to be? (FWIW, I was super-disappointed by a similar blade to the Lenox you linked... it was incredibly slow compared to a normal metal cutting disk in a handheld grinder.)

Comment: I used high tooth-count blades to cut aluminum screen door frames for years, in a fab shop.The best blades were carbide tipped thin-rim plywood blades, the right diameter for your saw. Any labeling as to the type of saw is just marketing...

Comment: This doesn't normally come up in circular saw blade discussion, but on 10" blades, there is a poorly-advertized saw blade dimension of "hook angle" that is important for certain types of saws or applications.  For instance, you would want a zero or slightly negative hook angle on a blade for a radial arm saw.  Negative hook is also recommended for cutting hard materials like aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly because 7-1/4" blades aren't of much use in a 10" miter saw (or even the rare 8" models), and vice versa.

They're both crosscut blades, so they could be used interchangeably, in theory.